# Which filesystem should I use for subversion on an EBS volume in EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, svn, filesystems, amazon-ebs

I'm building a subversion server for my company on ec2.
I'm installing an ubuntu image on an ebs instance, and I'll create another ebs volume for storing all the data (as the image of the server should not hold the data itself, only a configured server).

Which filesystem should I use on the EBS volume that will hold the svn data (and probably other data as well) ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For EBS volumes I prefer XFS since you can use the xfs-freeze to allow for simple snapshotting without having to detach the drive.  If you are not worried about that, check out whatever filesystem will best perform for your I/O needs.  Most data I have seen shows EXT4 and XFS to be the leaders, but they were not exhaustive by any means.